# How to can write the simplest form

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

I am trying to find the simplest form of a function that contains many different `Sign` to a function without the `Sign` function:

`1/2 (-2 (-1 + 2 t) Sign[1/2 - t] + 6 (-1 + t) Sign[1 - t] - 
   2 (-3 + 2 t) Sign[3/2 - t] + (-2 + t) Sign[2 - t] - t Sign[t])`

Comment: Is `t` real-valued?

Comment: Simply `FullSimplify[expr, t \[Element] Reals]`

Comment: @ J.M. Yes it is

Comment: @ corey979 Do you mean Simplify[...]?

Comment: Either of `SImplify[]` or `FullSimplify[]` should yield an expression containing `Abs[]`.

Comment: Is there any way to get the final answer as a piecewise function, i.e., without envolving /*Abs[]*/ ? Appreciate your help!

Comment: `Simplify[expr, Assumptions -> Element[t, Reals]]`

Comment: Have you looked at `PiecewiseExpand[]` already?